# Simple Web app:Django or Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

If I want to create a web app using Vue.js for frontend, what should I use, Django or Django Rest Framework?

Comment: This question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Django

Django is a web framework, where Django REST Framework is a Django library which can be used to build REST API on top of Django quickly, securely and easily.

You can't compare Django to Django-Rest-Framework any more than you can compare Windows to Oracle for Windows.

Django Rest Framework requires Django as a dependency. Further, Django can do everything that Django Rest Framework can do, you'd just have to write a lot of code to replicate the functionality of Django Rest Framework. DRF gives you a lot of convenience, like authentication modules, json serializers/deserializers, API routing and documentation, etc., etc.

But if you only need APIs for your app backend then DRF is your choice.

Credit and further reads :

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-Django-and-Django-REST-frameworks

https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/354yqt/django_regular_vs_django_rest_framework/

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework is a 3rd party library built on top of Django, which is a web framework. So by using DRF, you'd be using Django anyway.

That said, to work with any JS framework, DRF would make your life a lot easier. Though it's possible to integrate Vue.js directly into Django's templates.

Answer (score 0):

You should go for django rest framework to build app's APIs, then using Vue.js to consume its APIs

Comment: Answers should be based on facts, or provide explanations. This is barely a comment based on your unjustified opinion.